# Related to Hom, Images (im) and Kernels (ker)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Determine whether the following statements are correct or not and prove your claims:

1. If *f* ∈ *Hom(U,V)* and *g* ∈ *Hom(V,W)* such that *im(f)* ⊂ *ker(g)*, then *g ◦ f* = 0
2. If *f* ∈ *Hom(U,V)* and *g* ∈ *Hom(V,W)* such that *im(f)* ∩ *ker(g)*= {0}, then *g ◦ f* is isomorphic

I am quite puzzled about the concepts of Hom, images and kernels, so please help me. I may need some detailed explanations to understand these concepts.

Comment: your second statement is not clear.Did you mean  $im(f) ∩ ker(g)=\{0\}$

Comment: Are there additional hypothesis about $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ v \in U$

$ v \in U \Rightarrow f(v) \in im(f)$

$ im(f) ⊂ ker(g) \Rightarrow f(v) \in ker(g)$

$f(v) \in ker(g) \Rightarrow g(f(v))=0$

$g(f(v))=0 \Rightarrow g ◦ f = 0 $

Answer (score 1):

Hom(X, Y) (Homomorphism, X and Y are vector spaces) A function from X to Y which preserves scalar multiplication ($f(cx) = cf(x)$ for any c in the scalar field) and addition of vectors ($f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for any $x, y \in X$) (I assume you are working with vector spaces here because of the linear algebra tag)

Im(f) (image)  the set of all outputs of F. if f is a function from A to B then $b \in Im(B)$ if and only if there exists $a \in A$ such that f(a) = b

Ker(f) (kernel) the subset of Im(f) such that $a \in Ker(f) \Leftrightarrow f(a) = 0$

I think that Nevzat Eren Akkaya's answer answers question 1 as well as I could and if the clarification is given for Q2 then I will answer it if someone hasn't before me

Answer (score 1):

I will write a group-theoretical answer since there are two correct answers before of mine.

By definition,
$$Hom(U,V) = \{f: U \to V: f\text{ is a homomorphism}\}$$
and given some $g \in Hom(V,W)$,
$$\ker g = \{v \in V: g(v) = 0\}.$$
So, if $f(u) \in \ker g$, then $g(f(u)) = 0$ and since it holds for every $u \in U$, then $g \circ f = 0$ where $0$ is the zero map.

The item $2$ is incomplete, I will try to write an answer assuming some facts.

$$\ker g \circ f = \{u \in U : (g\circ f)(u) = 0\}.$$
Since $im(f) \cap \ker g = \{0\}$, $g(f(u)) = 0$ if and only if $f(u) = 0$. In that point you need to show that $f(u) = 0$ if and only if $u = 0$, otherwise if $f(u) = 0$ for some $u \neq 0$, then $g(f(u)) = (g\circ f)(u) = 0$ for some $u \neq 0$ which implies the non injectivity of $g \circ f$. So, assuming $f$ injective, $(g \circ f)(u) = 0$ if and only if $u = 0$ so that $g \circ f$ is injective. Also, you need to show that $g \circ f$ is surjective, that is, given $w \in W$ there is some $u \in U$ such that $(g\circ f)(u) = w$. If $g$ is not surjective, there is $w \in W$ such that $g(v) \neq w$ for every $v \in V$, so $g$ must be surjective.

---

**If $f$ is not injective:**

Define $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$ and $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by $g(x) = x$. Then $im(f)\cap \ker g = \{0\}$ but $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(0) = 0$.

**If $g$ is not surjective:**

Define $f: \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{Q}$ by $f(x) = x$ and $g: \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{R}$ by $g(x) = x$. Then $im(f) \cap \ker g = \{0\}$ but there is no $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $(g \circ f)(x) = \pi$.